# What does d refer to in %r11d in this x86 instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I have a function fn() that allocates a 64 byte buffer on the stack and then calls the gets function. **Note:** I am using gets in order to overwrite the return address on the stack.

```
void fn() {
    char buf[64];
    gets(buf);
}
```

The code has been compiled with the modified gcc compiler for Native Client. If we look at address 20243 we pop the top of the stack into register r11. Then, on the next line, we move the contents of this register in %ebp.

However, I don't understand what the **d** at the end of `%r11d` refers to. I can't find a reference in the x86 instruction set (perhaps I missed it) so could it be GAS syntax? Can someone explain?

```
0000000000020220 <fn>:
   20220:       55                      push   %rbp
   20221:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   20224:       83 ec 40                sub    $0x40,%esp
   20227:       4c 01 fc                add    %r15,%rsp
   2022a:       8d 45 c0                lea    -0x40(%rbp),%eax
   2022d:       89 c7                   mov    %eax,%edi
   2022f:       66 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84    data32 data32 nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   20236:       00 00 00 00 00
   2023b:       e8 a0 12 00 00          callq  214e0 <gets>
   20240:       48 89 ec                mov    %rbp,%rsp
   20243:       41 5b                   pop    %r11
   20245:       44 89 dd                mov    %r11d,%ebp
   20248:       4c 01 fd                add    %r15,%rbp
   2024b:       41 5b                   pop    %r11
   2024d:       41 83 e3 e0             and    $0xffffffe0,%r11d
   20251:       4d 01 fb                add    %r15,%r11
   20254:       41 ff e3                jmpq   *%r11
   20257:       66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

Comment: d = doubleword, w = word, b = byte

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from [Gentle Introduction to x86-64 Assembly](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/assembly.html):

> **Register set extensions**
>   X86-64 defines eight new integer registers named r8-r15. These registers are encoded using special REX prefix and so using them in non-64-bit instruction implies instruction length growth by 1 byte. They are named as follows:
>
> rXb for 8 bit register (containing the lowest byte of the 64-bit value)
>     rXw for 16 bits
>     **rXd for 32 bits**
>
>     rX  for 64 bits